# Dropdown moving all contents under it?

Tags: css

I have a dropdown that will show some content.

```
<ul class="menus" style="">
    <li>hey</li>
</ul>
```

And this is the css:

```
.menus {
    width: 607px;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #9f9f9f;
    border-left: solid 1px #9f9f9f;
    border-right: solid 1px #9f9f9f;
    bottom: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    position:relative;
}

.menus li {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #d6d6d6;
}

.menus li:hover {
    background-color: #71bfdb;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #3fb7d3;
    border-top: solid 1px #3fb7d3;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menus li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Whenever the dropdown opens, All of the content moving to the bottom, depending on how long the list is.

**Question**

How can I prevent this?
If I put position absolute, the whole dropdown will go crazy, like move positions, not like I wanted.

Comment: You _need_ position absolute to take it out of normal flow. You'll then need to position it relative to the anchor element with JS

Comment: it's not a "real" dropdown, so you're dynamically modifying the dom, causing thigns to reflow when the dropdown is opened. you'll need to do some hackery, e.g. make the element fixed/absolute while it's "open" so it won't affect the rest of the layout.

Comment: Check my example - http://jsfiddle.net/tKmGB/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position: absolute` to remove it from the flow of the page (`relative` means it is still in the page flow, which is what causes it to push content after it down).

You can change where an absolutely positioned element shows up by using the `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` css properties (i.e. `top: 0px; left: 10px;`).  These pixel values are relative to the first parent element with `position: relative`, so if you relatively position the parent element it should be simple to get it displayed in the appropriate place on the page.

That should address your concern of absolute positioning causing it to 'go crazy' as you put it!